# Spring Security 3.1 using Active Directory

Tags: spring, active-directory, spring-security

I'm trying to secure my Spring 3.1 web app with Spring Security 3.1, and I need to use Active Directory for user authentication.
However, I cant seem to find the complete configuration steps. I tried different bits of suggestions but they didn't work for me.

What are the complete steps of configuration to enable a Spring 3.1 web app to use Spring Security 3.1 with Active Directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<beans:bean id="adAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="[your domain]" />
    <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://[your AD server]:389" />
    <beans:property name="userDetailsContextMapper">
        <beans:bean class="[your user-details context mapper]" />
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">

    <authentication-provider ref="adAuthProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

If you need to provide custom logic for mapping user and authorities from the AD entry, you can implement your own `UserDetailsContextMapper` implementation and specify it in the `userDetailsContextMapper` property on the adAuthProvider bean.